# What could be causing 42-second failed calls to Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm debugging a problem with my Azure web app right now. Certain calls from it to Azure Table Storage are taking very long amounts of time and then failing.

Looking at my Application Insights dashboard, it appears that most of the calls that fail are to a few particular tables, tables that contain large amounts of data. It also seems that once one call fails, several others fail too at the same time, so that the failures occur as clusters of about five or six calls at a time, usually within the same second. The calls that fail usually fail after either 21 or 42 seconds.

I'm starting to suspect that this might be a result of hitting the Performance Target thresholds of 2K items per partition or 20K items total, per second. The documentation says that when that happens, Azure Table Storage will start sending 500 and 503 errors. Unfortunately, the `Result Code` field in Application Insights shows `<undefined>` for the failing calls, so I have no way of confirming what it actually was. (Or maybe the call timed out and was canceled before ever receiving a response.)

**Do the symptoms I'm seeing support my hypothesis that I'm hitting Azure Table Storage performance target thresholds?** I want to be sure I'm focusing my efforts in the right direction.

**Edit**: Many of the queries that are actually failing are ones that should be very fast: they specify both a PartitionKey and a RowKey. I suspect that even these queries are failing after I hit my performance target threshold.

In response to the comments, here are a few queries that I'm the most suspicious of:

```
var filter =
    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, UserArticleViewEntity.GeneratePartitionKeyRangeStart(userID)),
        TableOperators.And,
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, UserArticleViewEntity.GeneratePartitionKeyRangeEnd(userID))
    );
```

This will generate a query for a range of partitions that all start with the same prefix. There may be dozens to hundreds of partitions. Each partition will usually contain one or two entities.

```
string filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, userID);
filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter, TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("NextDueDate", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, dueDateGreaterThanOrEqualTo));
filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter, TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("NextDueDate", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, dueDateLessThanOrEqualTo));
filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter, TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("WhenUpdated", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, lastEncounteredGreaterThanOrEqualTo));
filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter, TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("WhenUpdated", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, lastEncounteredLessThanOrEqualTo));
filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter, TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForInt("Q", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, qGreaterThanOrEqualTo));
filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter, TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForInt("Q", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, qLessThanOrEqualTo));
```

I think this is probably the most likely culprit. I understand that it will need to scan the entire partition. Each partition could have hundreds or thousands of rows.

I apologize if my original question was imprecise. Let me rephrase it. Assuming that some of my queries are indeed causing large table scans, is it expected that this would cause a spillover effect and cause other queries to fail? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tables that contain large amounts of data - how much data, how have you partitioned these tables, and how are they being queried?

Comment: can you add the code to your application that would log there errors the the response you are getting? also take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn782840.aspx

Comment: Azure Storage doesn't have a guaranteed 2K/sec rate on a partition - that's a general scalability target. But anything's just a guess at this point - you haven't shown any code, any logs, etc.

Comment: @BrendanGreen I've added code and notes.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I've added code and notes. Sorry about my imprecise question. I'm mainly wondering if it's expected that hitting performance target thresholds could cause spillover effects to other queries (even ones that specify both PK and RK).

Comment: You could try to use the Try/Catch block to catch exceptions , and write explicit code to [send exception telemetry](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-search-diagnostic-logs/#trace) in Catch block, which could help us find application exception reports.